# Highlight row range if column value is greater than zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with various data in C5 to H?. The H length will vary on different worksheets but will be greater than 2,000 depending on the worksheet.

So, I need a VBA macro that will check the value in every cell in the H column and if there is a value greater than zero, highlight that row from the C column to the L column.

Comment: This is probably better done with some conditional formatting.

Comment: I prefer to use VBA.

Comment: `The H length will vary on different worksheets but will be greater than 2000 depending on the worksheet` what do you mean by this? And what have you tried so far? *Conditional formatting* I think is the best way to go.

Comment: I will be using different worksheets. maybe worksheet1 will contain data from C5 to H2100. Worksheet2 will contain data from C5 to H2410, etc.Most of the macros that I have found highlight every other row, but I need to highlight the row only if there is a value greater than 0. Again, I prefer to use a VBA macro, not conditional formatting.

Comment: I have found many macros that come close to what i want to do, but I have not been successful in modifying them to do what I want. I would think that this would be fairly easy for someone that has experience with VBA.

Comment: I have been working on this myself for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub ColorMeElmo()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "H").Value
        If v > 0 Then
            Range("C" & i & ":L" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```